# Hide table structure to users in firebird

Tags: firebird

I have been searching for a way to hide tables structures for some user but without success. I need that some users can only browse two views, but they don't be able to browse tables structures.
Is there any way?

Comment: AFAIK you can't (although it might be possible to revoke select rights from the metadata tables; that could potentially break tools and other things though).

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to *hide* things from Users.

You should only *grant* them access to the things they actually need to work with.

Comment: Yes. I have done this. I only grant what I want, but I want the user can't view the database structure. That is what I want to avoid.